# String is not null terminated error

Tags: c++, cstring

I'm having a string is not null terminated error, though I'm not entirely sure why. The usage of std::string in the second part of the code is one of my attempt to fix this problem, although it still doesn't work.

My initial codes was just using the buffer and copy everything into client_id[]. The error than occurred. If the error is correct, that means I've got either client_ id OR theBuffer does not have a null terminator. I'm pretty sure client_id is fine, since I can see it in debug mode. Strange thing is buffer also has a null terminator. No idea what is wrong.

```
char * next_token1 = NULL;
char * theWholeMessage = &(inStream[3]);
theTarget = strtok_s(theWholeMessage, " ",&next_token1);
sendTalkPackets(next_token1, sizeof(next_token1) + 1, id_clientUse, (unsigned int)std::stoi(theTarget));
```

Inside sendTalkPackets is. I'm getting a string is not null terminated at the last line.

```
void ServerGame::sendTalkPackets(char * buffer, unsigned int buffersize, unsigned int theSender, unsigned int theReceiver)
{
std::string theMessage(buffer);
theMessage += "0";

const unsigned int packet_size = sizeof(Packet);
char packet_data[packet_size];
Packet packet;
packet.packet_type = TALK;

char client_id[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];


char theBuffer[MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE];
strcpy_s(theBuffer, theMessage.c_str());
//Quick hot fix for error "string not null terminated"

const char * test = theMessage.c_str();
sprintf_s(client_id, "User %s whispered: ", Usernames.find(theSender)->second.c_str());
printf("This is it %s ", buffer);
strcat_s(client_id, buffersize , theBuffer);
```

Comment: `theMessage += "0";`  Were you expecting that this adds a null terminator?  If so, it doesn't.

Comment: Also, there is no need to do any of this char array and pointer manipulations to this extent.  You can work entirely with `std::string`, and only when a function calls for a `const char*` do you eventually use the `c_str()` member function to obtain the C-style string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yea that was actually a code leftover from one of my tries. Now I'm trying to use strings to manipulate it.

Comment: If you really wanted to null terminate the string (which is not needed anyway), you would do `theMessage.push_back(0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methinks that problem lies in this line:

```
sendTalkPackets(next_token1, sizeof(next_token1) + 1, id_clientUse, (unsigned int)std::stoi(theTarget));
```

sizeof(next_token1)+1 will always gives 5 (on 32 bit platform) because it return size of pointer not size of char array.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which could be causing this (or other problems): As
`buffersize`, you pass `sizeof(next_token1) + 1`.  `next_token1` is
a pointer, which will have a constant size of (typically) 4 or 8.  You
almost certainly want `strlen(next_token1) + 1`.  (Or maybe without the
`+ 1`; conventions for passing sizes like this generally only include
the `'\0'` if it is an output buffer.  There are a couple of other
places where you're using `sizeof`, which may have similar problems.

But it would probably be better to redo the whole logic to use
`std::string` everywhere, rather than all of these C routines.  No
worries about buffer sizes and `'\0'` terminators.  (For protocol
buffers, I've also found `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<unsigned char>`
quite useful.  This was before the memory in `std::string` was
guaranteed to be contiguous, but even today, it seems to correspond more
closely to the abstraction I'm dealing with.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do

```
std::string theMessage(buffer);
theMessage += "0";
```

This fails on two fronts:

- The `std::string` constructor doesn't know where `buffer` ends, if `buffer` is not 0-terminated. So `theMessage` will potentially be garbage and include random stuff until some zero byte was found in the memory beyond the buffer.
- Appending string "0" to `theMessage` doesn't help. What you want is to put a zero byte somewhere, not  value 0x30 (which is the ascii code for displaying a zero).

The right way to approach this, is to poke a literal zero byte `buffersize` slots beyond the start of the buffer. You can't do that in `buffer` itself, because `buffer` may not be large enough to accomodate that extra zero byte. A possibility is:

```
char *newbuffer = malloc(buffersize + 1);
strncpy(newbuffer, buffer, buffersize);
newbuffer[buffersize] = 0; // literal zero value
```

Or you can construct a `std::string`, whichever you prefer.